# Chessboard with named squares in foreign language

Tags: chess, chessboard

I am trying to translate an example from the documentation of the [chessboard package](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf), page 54. The code's example is:

```
\setchessboard{tinyboard,color=magenta,clearboard}
\chessboard[pgfstyle={[base,at={\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.4ex}}]text},
            text= \fontsize{1.2ex}{1.2ex}\bfseries\sffamily\currentwq,
            markboard]
```

I added in the `setchessboard` part the command: `vlabelformat=\mytranslator{\value{filelabel}}`.
The command successfully translates the labels outside the board (a-h) but it doesn't apply to the names inside. I would expect the names to use the current format but it seems that's not the case.

Assuming I haven't missed anything obvious in the labels formatting I guess I should pass `\currentwq` to a function and call mytranslator from within but I don't know how to do this. Any ideas?

EDIT: Added a MWE. The translator is bit a dummy; instead I use babel to type my letter of choice.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xskak}

\newcommand\mytranslator[1]{\ifcase#1 \or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\fi}

\begin{document}


    \setchessboard{boardfontsize=30pt,color=blue,clearboard,
                   vlabelformat=\mytranslator{\value{filelabel}}}
    
    \chessboard[pgfstyle={[base,at={\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.4ex}}]text},
                text= \fontsize{1.2ex}{1.2ex}\bfseries\sffamily\currentwq,
                markboard,showmover=false]

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't show only a code snippet. Always show a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I agree that `vlabelformat` could be propagated to `\currentwq` (and the other `\currentxx` macros), as a workaround you can write a wrapper around `\currentwq` that calls your translator function.

Here `xstring` is used to extract the individual characters from the field name because I couldn't make that work with standard `\@firstofone` or expl3 commands :) the filelabel counter is reverse calculated from the letter by subtracting 96 from the character code.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand\mytranslator[1]{\ifcase#1 \or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\or a\fi}

\newcommand{\fieldtranslate}[1]{%
\StrChar{#1}{1}[\fileletter]%
\StrChar{#1}{2}[\rank]%
\edef\filenumber{\numexpr`\fileletter-96\relax}%
\mytranslator{\filenumber}\rank%
}

\begin{document}
    \setchessboard{boardfontsize=30pt,color=blue,clearboard,
                   vlabelformat=\mytranslator{\value{filelabel}}}
    
    \chessboard[pgfstyle={[base,at={\pgfpoint{0pt}{-0.4ex}}]text},
                text= \fontsize{1.2ex}{1.2ex}\bfseries\sffamily\fieldtranslate{\currentwq},
                markboard,showmover=false]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. That was what I had in mind but I didn't know how to cut the string in two characters.